# Android access file in Firebase cloud storage whilst still offline

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I need to show images taken by the user in my application. I storing them in `FirebaseFirestore` with the following code:

```
StorageReference imagesRef = storage.getReference("images/"+device.ref+"/"+timeStamp+".png");

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(output.toString());
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();

UploadTask uploadTask = imagesRef.putBytes(image);
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    }
});
```

This works well, and when I am offline and I then go online the files nicely auto upload to `Storage`.

However even when offline I still need to be able to access this image. I am accessing the image normally with the following code:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference().child("images/"+device+"/"+image.getFilename());

try {
    File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
    localFile.deleteOnExit();

    storageReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Log.v("Download", "downloaded");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However if I 'upload' am image whilst offline I can't seem to get it back, is there a reason for this, or perhaps a work around? Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: When you try to upload image while offline, the image uploads as soon as you get online. To access that image you should first upload it and then get it.

Comment: But I would like to display the image whilst the user is still offline, is there any way around that?

Comment: You can use local image file (as you said).

Comment: I know I can, but the reference for that file is in the firebase storage, which until uploaded I can't access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Storage for Firebase doesn't have an "offline" mode for dealing with files.  It's not like Realtime Database and Firestore.  You can only download a file while online, and you can't download a file that hasn't finished uploading while online.  If you need to deal with files while offline, you should do that with your own local cache.

Comment: Okay fair point, do you know of any solutions that might be able to provide this, AWS springs to mind but not sure about its `offline` mode.